# How to set datacombo default in visual basic 6

Tags: vb6

I'd like to set the default selected value for a datacombo.
What I have now is:

```
Set RSest = New ADODB.Recordset
    RSest.Open "Select * from CTR_Estados order by descripcion", DbLink, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    Set DCestados.DataSource = RSest
    Set DCestados.RowSource = RSest
    DCestados.BoundColumn = "id_Estado"
    DCestados.ListField = "descripcion"
```

Answer (score 1):

I poked around a little bit and the only way I could find to select an item in the DataCombo was like this:

```
DCestados.Text = "<description to select>"
```